# Difference between Interface and Abstract class in terms of Decoupling?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-2

As we know there are basically two important difference between Interface and Abstract class.

1. We can have function definitions in abstract class. This is advantageous when we want to add a function in a class without need to track down it's all implementations.
2. We can have multiple interface implementation.

I just came to know that we can differentiate between them in terms of Decoupling?

Your comments...

**Also if you can you provide a very basic link that explains the Decoupling for Interface and Abstract class ?**

We normally use **Business Logic Layer**, **Data Access Layer**(contains abstract functions) and **DataAccess.SqlServer Layer**. Right? Despite of the fact that we aware of the Business needs, why are we creating **Data Access Layer**(contains abstract functions), Why can't **Business Logic layer** directly access **DataAccess.SqlServer Layer**?

Comment: Golden rule: Abstract: Is-A and Interface: Can-Do. E.g.: Asian, is a person, and phone can play mp3 (and also does a CD player, an ipod, etc..)

Answer (score 19):

**Decoupling**

In programming and design, this is generally the act of making code which is re-usable with as few dependencies as possible.

**Factory Pattern In This Context**

When using the Factory Pattern, you have a centralized factory which can create objects without necessarily defining them itself. That would be up to the object's definition.

**Abstract and Interface**

*Interface*

Defining an interface is best practice, as it allows for a light weight type to be used for inference, and also provides a blueprint which all inheriting classes must abide by. For example, `IDisposable` must implement the `Dispose` method. Note that this is decoupled from the interface, as each class inheriting `IDisposable` will define its own function of the `Dispose` method.

*Abstract*

Abstract is similar to interface in that it is used for inheritance and inference, but it contains definitions which all classes will inherit. Something to the extent of every automobile will have an engine so a good abstract class for automobile could include a predefined set of methods for an engine.

### **Edit**

**Explanation**

Here you will see a simple example of inheritance using an interface and an abstract class. The decoupling occurs when the interface is inherited by an abstract class and then it's methods are customized. This allows for a class to inherit the abstract class and still have the same type as the interface. The advantage is that the class inheriting the abstract class can be used when the expected type is the original interface.

**Decoupling**

That advantage allows for any implementation to be used which conforms to the expected interface. As such, many different overloads can be written and passed in. Here is an example of one.

**Example**

*Interface Definition*

```
public interface IReady
{
    bool ComputeReadiness();
}
```

*Inheritance*

```
public abstract class WidgetExample : IReady
{
    public int WidgetCount { get; set; }
    public int WidgetTarget { get; set; }
    public bool WidgetsReady { get; set; }

    public WidgetExample()
    {
        WidgetCount = 3;
        WidgetTarget = 45;
    }

    public bool ComputeReadiness()
    {
        if (WidgetCount < WidgetTarget)
        {
            WidgetsReady = false;
        }
        return WidgetsReady;
    }
}


public class Foo : WidgetExample
{
    public Foo()
    {
        this.WidgetTarget = 2;
    }
}

public class Bar : IReady
{
    public bool ComputeReadiness()
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

*Decoupling*

```
public class UsesIReady
{
    public bool Start { get; set; }
    public List<string> WidgetNames { get; set; }

    //Here is the decoupling. Note that any object passed
    //in with type IReady will be accepted in this method
    public void BeginWork(IReady readiness)
    {
        if (readiness.ComputeReadiness())
        {
            Start = true;
            Work();
        }
    }

    private void Work()
    {
        foreach( var name in WidgetNames )
        {
            //todo: build name
        }
    }
}
```

*Polymorphism*

```
public class Main
{
    public Main()
    {
        //Notice that either one of these implementations 
        //is accepted by BeginWork

        //Foo uses the abstract class
        IReady example = new Foo();
        UsesIReady workExample = new UsesIReady();
        workExample.BeginWork(example);

        //Bar uses the interface
        IReady sample = new Bar();
        UsesIReady workSample = new UsesIReady();
        workSample.BeginWork(sample);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see any reason to mark your `WidgetExample` class abstract. It does not exposes any abstract methods that should be implemented by child classes.

Comment: @TravisJ Can you give an example that shows against decoupling.

Comment: @ytftyffty - Nope, can't think of one. There should be no reason not to decouple.

Comment: It's like a factory pattern which explains that you must not create instance of once class in other class and just pass the class instance to the argument in the function and the function argument will be an interface. But where is the difference between Interface and Abstract class in terms of Decoupling. Am I correct ?

Answer (score 6):

I've been looking through the answers, and they all seem a little complicated for the question. So here is my (hopefully) simpler answer.

- **Interface** should be used when **none** of the implementation **details** are available to the current scope of the code.
- **Abstracts** should be used when **some** of the implementation **details** are available to you
- And, for completeness, when **all** of the implementation **details** are available you should be using **classes**.

In terms of decoupling, while I somewhat agree with Shelakel, for the purposes of this question, and stating fully decoupled design practices, I would suggest the following:

- **Always** use **Interfaces** to define external behaviour.
- When you have **some** of the implementation **details** available, use
  **abstract** classes to define them, but implement the **interfaces on
  the abstract classes**, and inherit from those classes in turn.

This ensures that later if you need to change some obscure implementation detail in a new implementation you are able to do so without modifying the existing abstract class, and are also able to group different implementation types into different abstract classes.

EDIT: I forgot to include the link :)
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11155/Abstract-Class-versus-Interface

Comment: We normally use **Business Layer**, **Data Access Layer(contains abstract functions)** and **DataAccess.SqlServer Layer**. Right? Despite of the fact that we aware of the Business needs, why are we creating **Data Access Layer(contains abstract functions)**, Why can't **Business Logic layer** directly access **DataAccess.SqlServer Layer**? I am asking this question after reading your lines **Interface should be used when none of the implementation details are available to the current scope of the code**

Comment: When I refer to scope, I am referring the layers.
The idea of decoupling is for 2 main reasons:
1. Modularize code blocks for maintainability.
2. Be able to replace certain blocks of code without interfering with the operations of external code.

If you decide to change to an Oracle database you will be able to do so by implementing a replacement layer for DataAccess.SqlServer layer, and possibly some small modifications in your Data Access Layer, and you should have no changes in your Business Layer. Thats the theory anyway... I don't think I've ever seen it work perfectly in the wild :)

Answer (score 3):

Abstract classes and interfaces are not MUTUALLY EXCLUSIVE choices. I often define both an Interface and an abstract class that implements that interface.

The interface ensure the maximum decoupling because it doesnt force your class to belong to a specific inheritance hierarchy, so your class may inherit from whichever other class. In other terms any class can inherit from an Interface, while classes that already inherits from other classes cannot inherit from an abstract class.

On the other side in an abstract class you can factor out code that is common to all implementations, while with Interfaces you are forced to implement everything from the scratch.
As a conclusion, often the best solution is using BOTH an abstract class and an Interface, so one can move from re-using the common code contained in the abstract class, if possible, to re-implementing the interface from the scratch, if needed.

Answer (score 3):

Decoupling for the sake of decoupling is a futile exercise.

Interfaces are meant to be used for integration where the specifics aren't required to be known to be of use (ex. SendEmail()). Common uses include components, services, repositories and as markers for IOC and generic implementations.

Extension methods with generic type constraints that include interfaces allow functionality similar to traits found in Scala with similar composability.

```
public interface IHasQuantity { double Quantity { get; } }
public interface IHasPrice { decimal PricePerUnit { get; } }

public static class TraitExtensions
{
    public static decimal CalculateTotalPrice<T>(this T instance)
        where T : class, IHasPrice, IHasQuantity
    {
        return (decimal)instance.Quantity * instance.PricePerQuantity;
    }
}
```

In my opinion, abstract classes and class inheritance is overused.

SOLID design principles teach us that Liskov's substitution principle implies that class inheritance should only be used if the inherited class is substitutable for the ancestor. This means that all methods should be implemented (no throw new NotImplementedExeption()) and should behave as expected.

I personally have found class inheritance useful in the case of the Template Method pattern as well as for state machines. Design patterns such as the builder pattern are in most cases more useful than deep chains of inheritance.

Now back to your question; interfaces should be used most if not all of the time. Class inheritance should be used internally and only externally for purposes of definition, whereafter an interface should be used for interaction and the concrete implementation provided via a factory or to be injected via an IOC container.

Ideally when using external libraries, an interface should be created and an adapter implemented to expose only the functionality required. Most of these components allow to be configured beforehand or at runtime to be resolved via an IOC container.

In terms of decoupling, it is important to decouple the application from its implementations (especially external dependencies) to minimize the reasons to change.

I hope that my explanation points you in the right direction. Remember that it's preferred to refactor **working** implementations and thereafter interfaces are defined to expose functionality.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not going to discuss what are the pros/cons of these two constructs in general, as there are enough resources on that.

However, In terms of 'decoupling' a component from another, interface inheritance is much better than abstract classes, or class inheritance in general (In fact I don't think being abstract or not does not make much difference in terms of decoupling as all `abstract` does is prevent the class being instantiated without a concrete implementation).

Reason for above argument is, interfaces allow you to narrow down the exposure to absolute minimum of what required by the 'dependent component', if it requires a single method interface can easily do that, or even be a marker interface without any method. This might be difficult with a base class (abstract or concrete) as it should implement all the 'common' functionality for that base. Because of this a component dependent on the 'base type' will automatically 'see' all the common functionality even it does not need them for it's purposes.

Interfaces also gives you the best flexibility as even classes inheriting from bases which have nothing in common, can still implement an interface, and be used by the component expecting that interface. Good example of this is `IDisposable` interface.

So, my conclusion is for decoupling concern have all your components depend on interfaces than base types, and if you find most of your classes implementing that interface has a common implementation then have a base class implementing that interface and inherit other classes from that base.

Answer (score 1):

The *core* difference is this:

- Interfaces expose zero or more method *signatures* which all descendants *must* in turn implement (otherwise code won't even compile).
  Interface-exposed methods can either be implemented implicitly (every type derived from the interface has access to them) or explicitely (methods can be accessed only if you typecast the object to the interface type itself). [More details and an example can be found in this question](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229013%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).
- Abstract classes expose zero or more full-fledged methods, which descendants *can* either use or override, providing their own implementation. This approach allows you to define a customizable, "default" behavior. Abstract classes allows you to easily add new methods with no issues (`NotImplementedException` really shines when adding methods to abstract classes), whereas adding a method to an interface requires you to modify *all* the classes implementing it.

The final point is, that a class can implement *more than one* interface simultaneously.
Some real-world example might be:

- A hard drive which provides both USB and LAN ports is a good demonstration of multiple interface inheritance
- A Laptop which has a LED marked "bluetooth" but no bluetooth hardware on board is a good analogy of the concept of not implementing an abstract method (you have the LED, you have the little B symbol, but there's nothing under the roof).

**Edit 1**

Here's a [MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229013%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) explaining how to choose between interface and classes.

Comment: can you put some light on this sentence **"Do use abstract (MustInherit in Visual Basic) classes instead of interfaces to decouple the contract from implementations."** ?

Answer (score 1):

Defining a contract using an abstract class means that your implementers must inherit from this abstract class.  Since C# doesn't support multiple inheritance, these implementers will not be able to have an alternate class hierarchy, which can be pretty limiting for some.  In other words, an abstract class basically otherwise robs the implementer of the class hierarchy feature, which is often needed to get or use some other capabilities (of a framework or class library).

Defining a contract using an interface leaves the class hierarchy free for your implementers to use any way they see fit, in other words, providing much more freedom of implementation.

From a perspective of evaluation criteria, when we talk about coupling here we can speak to concerns of three separable authors, the client using (calling) the API/contract, the definer of the API/contract, and the implementer of the API/contract; we can speak to freedom (the fewer restrictions, the better), encapsulation (the less awareness necessary, the better), and resilience in the face of change.

I would offer that an interface results in looser coupling than an abstract class, in particular, between the definer and the implementer, due to higher freedom offered the implementer.

On the other hand, when it comes to versioning, you can at least add another method to the abstract class without necessarily requiring updates to subclass implementations, provided the added method has an implementation in the abstract class.  Versioning interfaces across DLL boundaries usually means adding another interface, much more complex to roll out.  (Of course, this is not a concern if you can refactor all the implementations together (say, because they're all in the same DLL)).

Answer (score 1):

The best way to understand and remember difference between ***interface*** and ***abstract class***, it's to remember that ***abstract class*** is a ***normal class*** and you can do everything with ***abstract class*** that you can do with the ***normal class with two exceptions***.

1. *You **can't instantiate** an abstract class*
2. *You can have **abstract method only in abstract class***

Answer (score 0):

Coding to interface provides reusability and polymorphism.As far as class implements interface,the interface or abstract class can be passed to parameter instead of class that implements the interface.Urs common technical problem is handled vis designing interface and abstract class and implementing it and giving subclass the specific functionality implementation.Imagine its like framework.Framework define interface and abstract class and implement it that is common to all.And those that are abstract is implemented by client according to its own requirement.

```
public interface Polymorphism{
void run();
Void Bark();
Energy getEnergy(Polymorphism test);
Public abstract class EnergySynthesis implements Polymorphism{
abstract void Energy();
Void Bark(){
 getEnergy(){

}
void run(){
getEnergy();

}public EnegyGeneartion extends EnergySynthesis  {
Energy getEnergy(Polymorphism test){
return new Energy( test); 
}
MainClass{

EnegyGeneartion test=new EnegyGeneartion ();
test.getEnergy(test);
test.Bark()
.
.
.
.
.
//here in Energy getEnergy(Polymorphism test) any class can be passed as parameter that implemets interface
```